# EKEventStore will not return Exchange Calendar items by external or local identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, exchange-server, ekeventstore

I am using the EKEventStore API to save events to the default calendar using the following:

EKEventStore - saveEvent:span:commit:error:.

Once the event is saved, I store the externalID and localID in my database for future reference using the following:

externalID = [myEvent calendarItemExternalIdentifier]; and
localID = [myEvent eventIdentifier].

The problem I am having is that when I then go back to try and retrieve the event using the following:

[[eventStore calendarItemsWithExternalIdentifier:externalID] firstObject]

OR

[eventStore eventWithIdentifier:localID],

iOS is not able to find my event.

If I run the exact same code, but have my default calendar set to an iCloud calendar, however, everything works correctly.

But if the default calendar is an Exchange calendar, I am getting the following error message:

"Error getting calendar item with UUID [insert externalID here]: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 "(null)""

Has anyone encountered this issue?

I have had this code deployed for over 2 years now and users recently reported they weren't able to open appointments created on Exchange calendars. Not sure what changed or when, but I have tested this on iOS 10 and 11, and both have the issue.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated,
Sincerely,
~Arash

Comment: hi, Recently from iOS 12 onwards am facing this issue. Outlook events are synced  till iOS 11 but from iOS 12 , the eventstore is not returning Exchange Events. Did you figured out the issue?

Comment: Hey GvSharma, please check my answer below. This is how we were able to workaround the issue. Let me know if you have any questions! Also, just a heads up, if you rely on the "EKEventStoreChangedNotification" notification to update any internal data regarding the calendar, we recently had a few of our users' devices throw a conniption fit. They were basically getting that notification every 2 seconds from iOS! :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not... we were able to work around this issue by including an internal reference ID in the notes of the event. Then, if both the externalEventID and eventID failed to return the event, which is our issue with Exchange, then we fall back to use the start and end date in an EKEventSearchCallback to look for our event.

Basically, it ends up looking like this:

```
EKEventSearchCallback searchBlock = ^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop)
{
    if([MyCustomClass event:event
 notesMatchesKnownValueDict:knownValueDict])
    {
        foundEvent = event;
        *stop = YES;
    }
};

NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                             endDate:endDate
                                                           calendars:nil];

[eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate usingBlock:searchBlock];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be waiting for the event to sync with Exchange. For example, I save the event and keep track of the ID assigned to it. Have a loop check every few seconds for a change. When the change happens, it's on the exchange server and you're good to reference that in your DB.

Try it out, let me know if it works!